# FLEX scrollable NavigatorContent

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, tabnavigator

I have a TabNaivgator which I fill in runtime with NavigatorContent filled in runtime as well with content.
I see though that my content is taller than the NavigatorContent height, but instead of creating a scrollbar, Flex makes the content exit the NavigatorContent bounds 
here is the code: http://pastebin.com/xxnSz6pk
and here is the result: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064417/Immagine.png

how do I make that content scroll?

thanx in advance

Comment: You probably need to set clipAndEnableScrolling property on the container/group, but it's hard to tell based on the code you've shown.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wVsm1ygs here is the full version

Answer (score 1):

Use the Scroller component inside the NavigationContent tags, and a Group inside the Scroller tags:

```
<s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%">
  <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Group>               
    <!-- Your component(s) here! -->
    </s:Group>
  </s:Scroller>
</s:NavigatorContent>
```